# What is the SQL for Find and Replace HTML Content?

Tags: mysql, html, database

So I have a database for a forum board, stored in a MySQL database called `forum`.

Inside it, I have a column called `post` in a table called `forum_posts`. There is some HTML I need to replace inside the `post` column, but it is stored between other characters (mostly text; more precisely, forum board conversations).

I have to replace this line:

```
<div width="95%" style="margin:8px 26px 4px 26px"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:spoil(this);"><div class='spoilertop'><b>SPOILER</b> [Show/Hide]</div></a><div style="display: none;" class="spoilermain">
```

With this line:

```
<div width="95%" style="margin:8px 26px 4px 26px"><a class='spoilertop' style='display:block;'><b>SPOILER</b> [Show/Hide]</a><div class="spoilermain">
```

I have tried this SQL (and some of its variations), but it always results to MySQL error.

```
SELECT * FROM `forum_posts` REPLACE(`post`, `<div width="95%" style="margin:8px 26px 4px 26px"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:spoil(this);"><div class='spoilertop'><b>SPOILER</b> [Show/Hide]</div></a><div style="display: none;" class="spoilermain">`, `<div width="95%" style="margin:8px 26px 4px 26px"><a class='spoilertop' style='display:block;'><b>SPOILER</b> [Show/Hide]</a><div class="spoilermain">`)
```

Is there any help?

Comment: your problem is your quotes ... dont use backticks on strings - as you have mixed quotes in your string you will need to escape them using `\`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a note if someone needs/wants to see what I did:

```
Update forum_posts
Set    post = replace(post, '<div width="95%" style="margin:8px 26px 4px 26px"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:spoil(this);"><div class=\'spoilertop\'><b>SPOILER</b> [Show/Hide]</div></a><div style="display: none;" class="spoilermain">', '<div width="95%" style="margin:8px 26px 4px 26px"><a class=\'spoilertop\' style=\'display:block;\'><b>SPOILER</b> [Show/Hide]</a><div class="spoilermain">');
WHERE  post LIKE '%<div width="95%" style="margin:8px 26px 4px 26px"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:spoil(this);"><div class=\'spoilertop\'><b>SPOILER</b> [Show/Hide]</div></a><div style="display: none;" class="spoilermain">%';
```

It was based on this: http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-replace-in-an-update-statement

All credits goes to @Teez though!

Answer (score 2):

Quote strings properly.

Try below:

```
SELECT REPLACE('post', '<div width="95%" style="margin:8px 26px 4px 26px"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:spoil(this);"><div class=\'spoilertop\'><b>SPOILER</b> [Show/Hide]</div></a><div style="display: none;" class="spoilermain">', '<div width="95%" style="margin:8px 26px 4px 26px"><a class=\'spoilertop\' style=\'display:block;\'><b>SPOILER</b> [Show/Hide]</a><div class="spoilermain">') as replacedpost FROM forum_posts;
```

Use `UPDATE forum_posts SET post=REPLACE(...._)  WHERE ...` if you want to update in database.

Comment: Still results in errror... it says, `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'REPLACE('post', '<div width="95%" style="margin:8px 26px 4px 26px"><a href="java' at line 1 `

Comment: OK! Need a bit work-around, but I managed to do this. Thanks! :)